# How far can one retrieve data from GitHub Archive?

Tags: github, google-bigquery, github-archive

The **[GitHub Archive](http://www.githubarchive.org/)**  project states

> GitHub Archive is a project to **record** the public GitHub timeline, **archive it**, and **make it easily accessible** for further analysis.

This archive is also queryable through **[Google Big Query](https://bigquery.cloud.google.com/)**. However, it looks like that I'm either missing something or only a portion of the data is available.

Indeed, running the following query only returns `1636` WatchEvents (*started* or *stopped*), whereas the **[Rails repository](https://github.com/rails/rails)** accounts more than `14300` watchers.

```
SELECT actor_attributes_login, created_at, payload_action
FROM [githubarchive:github.timeline]
where repository_name = "rails"
and type="WatchEvent"
order by created_at asc;
```

It looks like the oldest retrieved piece of data is more or less 2.5 months old.

Would the data be truncated (which might seem strange for an archive)? Is there a limit/quota I wouldn't know of related to the use of BigQuery?

[image: github-archive]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's correct. The project/crawler went live on March 11th of this year, hence the current archive starts on that day. There is a note about this on the [githubarchive.org](http://www.githubarchive.org/) page, but I guess I should make it more visible and explicit.

There is a thread with the GitHub team about making more of their history available, but I don't have an ETA for it yet. *fingers crossed* :-)

Comment: Thx for this answer and for the *awesome* GitHub Archive initiative!

Comment: You're right. There's a note I've overlooked which states *"timeline data is available starting March 11, 2012."*. I also think this statement *might* deserve some more exposure ;)